# Floating divs wrap even though container no-wrap?

Tags: html, css

There's some questions about this but I haven't found a good answer. Been looking for a couple hours now.

Here's my jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/foreyez/Mr2ER/

I have some simple markup:

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='box1'></div>
    <div class='box2'></div>
    <div class='box3'></div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.container {
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.box1 {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:red;
    float:left;
}

.box2 {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:green;
    float:left;
}

.box3 {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:blue;
    float:left;
}
```

Yet the boxes still wrap when the window is small enough. Any suggestions? 
Note: I want to keep this float:left, so no inline-block solutions please.

Comment: Why don't you want `inline-block` suggestions when what you are describing is exactly what `inline-block` does? http://jsfiddle.net/97B8e/

Comment: inline-block has issues. like adding unnecessary padding between elements. and then there's hacks to get it it work like font-size:0px which I don't want to deal with.

Comment: It isn't padding, it is simply white-space - remove the space and the 'issue' goes away. No hacks. Just a thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add `width:600px;` to the `.container` it will force them to stay inline.

Here's your [**updated JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ChubbyNinja/Mr2ER/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Give #container a width at least as large as the child divs:

```
.container {
    white-space:nowrap;
    width:9999px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Mr2ER/2/)**

Comment: why would you give it such a ridiculous width?

Comment: @DannyHearnah - It's just an example. As a wrote in my answer, the width should be at least as large as the width of the child divs. It's suited to dynamic content.